# Поиск в файле php

Tags: php, файлы, поиск, robots.txt

Есть txt файл. В нём 3 строки:

- Как дела?\Нормально\0   ( тут будет перенос коретки \n)
- Что делаешь?\ничего\0   ( тут будет перенос коретки \n)
- Как погода?\Ужасно\0    ( тут будет перенос коретки \n)

Нужно проверить весь файл, есть ли в нём "чёткое вхождение" строки-вопроса, например "Как дела?", проверять нужно с начала каждой строки до первого слеша в ней. если есть вхождение, вывести всё что после первого слеша \ и до символа \0, т.е. в примере это "Нормально".

Comment: У вас есть какие либо наработки по коду или вы хотите чтобы это сделали за вас? Приведите пример кода которым пытаетесь сделать описанные действия и сообщество сможет помочь

Comment: Ох уж эти тщетные попытки, сделать халявную фриланс биржу из сообщества ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$file_text = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$strs = explode("\n", $file_text);

$temp = [];
foreach ($strs as $str) { // получаем массив где ключ это вопрос а значение - ответ
    list($question, $answer, $more) = explode('\\', $str);
    $temp[$question] = $answer;
}

$question = 'Как дела?';

echo isset($temp[$question]) ? $temp[$question] : "Я незнаю ответа на этот вопрос!";

?>
```

Comment: Благодарю! всё отлично! поставьте плюс ему в карму за меня!